# Magento 2, how to redirect to my orders when click on My Account?

Tags: magento2.2, frontend, customer-account, dashboard

Using `Magento 2.2`, `Front-end`, `My Account`. I want to *redirect* to **My Order** when i click **My Account** from pop-menu.

[image]

Comment: redirect to **My Orders** when click **My Account** or **After login success**.

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change My Account link by plugin

Add below code to **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Url">
    <plugin name="custom_links" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Url" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Url.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Url
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;


    /**
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function afterGetAccountUrl(\Magento\Customer\Model\Url $subject, $result)
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('sales/order/history');
    }
}
```